# Frame Navigation Service not using Current culture on GoBack

Tags: wpf, user-controls, embedded-resource, currentculture, navigationservice

I am using a `Frame` object in my application to navigate through all of my screens (`user controls`).

My language page can be accessed from a couple different locations. When the new language is selected I use the `Frame.GoBack()` method to return to the previous screen. However, when I go back, the screen is still in the previously selected language. All pages navigated to thereafter are in the correct language.

We are setting the language by setting the threads `Culture` and the application automatically loads the translations from the correct resource file.

How can I force the Frame to reload the resources of the user control with the new culture or determine what type of page I was previously at and load that user control again?

I looked at this post, but I can not use what they explained. Because there is no public property that will allow instantiating the previous object.
[WPF/Silverlight NavigationService backstack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066024/wpf-silverlight-navigationservice-backstack)

I am setting the resources of the page in the XAML using:`"{x:Static resx:Translations.HelloWorld}"` and then setting the culture using:`Thread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo` & `Thread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo`

Comment: Just to clarify, if you go back one more time, will that page have the correct language? If so, will then going forward work? Obviously this isn't a solution that will work in all scenarios, but I'm interested if all pages in the back stack retain their original strings. Also, are you using `DynamicResource` or `StaticResource` (or maybe even `Binding`s) to access your localized strings?

Comment: Theoretically, yes; If I were to go back n times, it should load the current language I selected. Going forward currently works as described.
I am assuming that each page going back also has its original string, though I have yet to test this case.
I am using "{x:Static resx:Translations.HelloWorld}" and setting the Culture using Thread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo & Thread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo.